# React Native app crashing on TestFlight Release

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm able to run in release mode on my device and on simulator.
Not getting any issues when running with Zombies inspector tool.
Seems to be null dereference issue but cannot track it down.

How can I find out what location in code is causing this?
What next steps should I take to investigate or try to eliminate issues?

Also curious how I could figure out the function or line number for the log on line 8 for my app.

```
Incident Identifier: E41CBE15-1FAF-4ACD-88E1-E2A8D339E410
Beta Identifier:     A11056FE-EF4C-40D8-B3A8-23E848FF818A
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,2
Process:             MyAppName [2067]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78FD1DCF-EE86-4735-A7B7-BA62C038495E/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
Identifier:          com.MyAppName.app
Version:             2.0.1 (7)
AppStoreTools:       13A1030d
AppVariant:          1:iPhone14,2:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.MyAppName.app [800]

Date/Time:           2021-11-23 14:20:29.9420 -0500
Launch Time:         2021-11-23 14:20:29.7755 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.1 (19B74)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.15.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000065
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000065
VM Region Info: 0x65 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4374609819
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   104bf4000-104bf8000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...t.app/MyAppName
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL; [11]
Terminating Process: exc handler [2067]

Terminating Process: exc handler [2067]
Triggered by Thread:  8

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1999a564c getMethodNoSuper_nolock(objc_class*, objc_selector*) + 400
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1999a54e8 getMethodNoSuper_nolock(objc_class*, objc_selector*) + 44
2   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1999a24a4 lookUpImpOrForward + 376
3   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19999da84 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
4   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1999a4d44 objc_alloc_init + 80
5   UIKitCore                              0x183a7a948 -[UISheetPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 180
6   UIKitCore                              0x1837a1fd8 -[_UIRootPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingWindow:] + 80
7   UIKitCore                              0x183a1d798 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 484
8   MyAppName                                  0x104bf950c 0x104bf4000 + 21772
9   UIKitCore                              0x183a73044 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 356
10  UIKitCore                              0x183c5ab38 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3524
11  UIKitCore                              0x183c434a4 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1208
12  UIKitCore                              0x183aa0e44 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 152
13  UIKitCore                              0x1838f962c _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 104
14  UIKitCore                              0x183a24b7c __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 224
15  UIKitCore                              0x183b45380 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 248
16  UIKitCore                              0x183d85f8c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 760
17  UIKitCore                              0x183d11710 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340
18  UIKitCore                              0x1838fa430 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 196
19  UIKitCore                              0x1839ba350 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 892
20  UIKitCore                              0x1838fc340 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 276
21  UIKitCore                              0x1839e6df4 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 384
22  UIKitCore                              0x183e6e260 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.608 + 776
23  UIKitCore                              0x18392ac60 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 256
24  UIKitCore                              0x18396e524 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 288
25  UIKitCore                              0x183aa5d70 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 572
26  UIKitCore                              0x1839e50b4 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 388
27  FrontBoardServices                     0x192e34e20 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 440
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x192e5acdc __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.215 + 128
29  FrontBoardServices                     0x192e156b4 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240
30  FrontBoardServices                     0x192e16cf4 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 372
31  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180faf660 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
32  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb3118 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
33  FrontBoardServices                     0x192e16f94 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
34  FrontBoardServices                     0x192e163d4 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
35  FrontBoardServices                     0x192e1a9e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
36  CoreFoundation                         0x18135f020 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
37  CoreFoundation                         0x18136fce0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
38  CoreFoundation                         0x1812aa054 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
39  CoreFoundation                         0x1812af7f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 820
40  CoreFoundation                         0x1812c33b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
41  GraphicsServices                       0x19cc5338c GSEventRunModal + 164
42  UIKitCore                              0x183c636a8 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
43  UIKitCore                              0x1839e27f4 UIApplicationMain + 2092
44  MyAppName                                  0x104bf96b8 0x104bf4000 + 22200
45  dyld                                   0x105bc9a24 start + 520

Thread 1 name:   Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b82dd1a4 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb0054 _dlock_wait + 56
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fafdf8 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 56
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fbeb9c __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 364
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fbe744 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 144
5   MyAppName                                  0x104da5a54 0x104bf4000 + 1776212
6   MyAppName                                  0x104d8b0c0 0x104bf4000 + 1667264
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180faf660 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb0f08 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
9   MyAppName                                  0x104d8b09c 0x104bf4000 + 1667228
10  MyAppName                                  0x104d8b380 0x104bf4000 + 1667968
11  MyAppName                                  0x104d8044c 0x104bf4000 + 1623116
12  MyAppName                                  0x104d9b898 0x104bf4000 + 1734808
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fad914 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180faf660 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb6de4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb7958 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fc21a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec60f4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5e94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.accessibility.perappprefs.queue
Thread 3:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x181369c3c _CFXNotificationRegistrarAddName + 652
1   CoreFoundation                         0x181369be8 _CFXNotificationRegistrarAddName + 568
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1812e8d9c CFXNotificationRegistrarAdd + 512
3   CoreFoundation                         0x18131598c _CFXNotificationRegisterObserver + 248
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1812f57d4 CFNotificationCenterAddObserver + 348
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fad914 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180faf660 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb6de4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb7958 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fc21a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec60f4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5e94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b82dd1a4 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb0054 _dlock_wait + 56
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fafdf8 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 56
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fbeb9c __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 364
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fbe744 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 144
5   UIKitCore                              0x183abc398 __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3 + 136
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1812c62f4 __invoking___ + 148
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1812e3ac4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 468
8   Foundation                             0x182afaf00 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 24
9   Foundation                             0x182b1bda4 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 556
10  Foundation                             0x182af6a84 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 212
11  libxpc.dylib                           0x1f1efc32c _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 116
12  libxpc.dylib                           0x1f1eef85c _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 88
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180faf6e0 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fccec8 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 348
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb6cbc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 376
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fb798c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x180fc21a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec60f4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5e94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5e8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b82dc504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b82dcb9c mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1812ab688 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1812af97c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1812c33b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   Foundation                             0x182ade354 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236
6   Foundation                             0x182b1fc28 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                              0x183bdc8a4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524
8   Foundation                             0x182b2e36c __NSThread__start__ + 808
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec69a4 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   JavaScriptCore                         0x18c5a02b4 JSObjectSetProperty + 168
1   JavaScriptCore                         0x18c5a029c JSObjectSetProperty + 144
2   MyAppName                                  0x104e1ad38 0x104bf4000 + 2256184
3   MyAppName                                  0x104cfdf78 0x104bf4000 + 1089400
4   MyAppName                                  0x104cfc4d8 0x104bf4000 + 1082584
5   MyAppName                                  0x104e23540 0x104bf4000 + 2291008
6   MyAppName                                  0x104e17dd0 0x104bf4000 + 2244048
7   MyAppName                                  0x104d63b30 0x104bf4000 + 1506096
8   MyAppName                                  0x104d6fcf4 0x104bf4000 + 1555700
9   MyAppName                                  0x104d6faa8 0x104bf4000 + 1555112
10  CoreFoundation                         0x181316924 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28
11  CoreFoundation                         0x181317820 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 412
12  CoreFoundation                         0x1812af808 __CFRunLoopRun + 840
13  CoreFoundation                         0x1812c33b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
14  MyAppName                                  0x104d58e44 0x104bf4000 + 1461828
15  Foundation                             0x182b2e36c __NSThread__start__ + 808
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec69a4 _pthread_start + 148
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5ea0 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b82dcf90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ecd254 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x199a4be78 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 100
3   JavaScriptCore                         0x18d3e8b10 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 704
4   JavaScriptCore                         0x18d3e8544 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 16
5   JavaScriptCore                         0x18d3e9a00 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 48
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec69a4 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f1ec5ea0 thread_start + 8


Thread 8 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000109ded980   x1: 0x0000000109ded97d   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000109ded9ad
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x000000016b665c18   x6: 0x0000000000000065   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000109e00000   x9: 0x0000000000000004  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000109ded97c
   x12: 0x00000000669df065  x13: 0x0000000000000074  x14: 0x00000000d1a85000  x15: 0x0000000000085000
   x16: 0x00000001f1ebda50  x17: 0x00000001dd3f8260  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000109d38068
   x20: 0x000000016b665c18  x21: 0x0000000109e00000  x22: 0x0000000109d8d9b8  x23: 0x0000000000000065
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000109dce808  x26: 0x0000000106828040  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000028265e7c0   fp: 0x000000016b665c00   lr: 0x894c9b818c5a029c
    sp: 0x000000016b665b90   pc: 0x000000018c5a02b4 cpsr: 0x40001000
   far: 0x0000000000000065  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x19999c000 -        0x1999d5fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <10fa90c6dfe538aeb3dc2251181cc272> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x18374a000 -        0x184fcefff UIKitCore arm64e  <8388eb03002b3b35a78a6a022894292e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x104bf4000 -        0x1055e3fff MyAppName arm64  <88e3b5ce9df93ebcb845ba7abd349e08> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78FD1DCF-EE86-4735-A7B7-BA62C038495E/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
       0x192e0b000 -        0x192eb6fff FrontBoardServices arm64e  <6fdec0c3e5003e06948ee34bda520801> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
       0x180fab000 -        0x180ff1fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <a5cbaab3e3893548baacfab18411b94a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1812a4000 -        0x1816f7fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <b2d21cfd378c36d5baf73f70599cfefc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x19cc52000 -        0x19cc5afff GraphicsServices arm64e  <44e4515eb18737f18fe028e7b087daf5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x105bb0000 -        0x105c07fff dyld arm64e  <c21dba379df93fc7b286734030e18bb1> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1b82db000 -        0x1b830efff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <b1b942de75903c61980a19d80ed4da37> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1f1ec5000 -        0x1f1ed0fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <1a4a45fd1bb639df84140590ce103717> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x182ac6000 -        0x182dcbfff Foundation arm64e  <d59c69755af237bc93be43b80b4293a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1f1ee0000 -        0x1f1f17fff libxpc.dylib arm64e  <c4b164ee546f365786ee230d897ef6a0> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
       0x18c232000 -        0x18d4f2fff JavaScriptCore arm64e  <488fd070baee3b55ac28cee0d299f2b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
       0x199a42000 -        0x199aa5fff libc++.1.dylib arm64e  <255864c483d93bac8c7aad1b2d8a60cc> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sentry to see the logs for production app :
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/

Answer (score 0):

In React Native newer version i got the same issue and here is the solution which worked for me

Go To:

> ```
> TARGETS -> {Your_App} -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries ->
> Keep LibPods-{Your_App}.a and Remove Other items
> ```
>
> [Please checkout the image for better understanding...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRVPX.png)